# Not able to retrieve the response data from Python request

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

While trying to fetch response from a website I am getting the data in JSON response. But in the console it's showing the data is present.

I had tried and getting the response as

```
"{'Page': '1', 
  'TotalPage': '538', 
  'CurrentPage': '53794', 
  'Total': '53794', 
  'Data': '[{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},
            {},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},
            {},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},
            {},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},
            {},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},
            {},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},
            {},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},
            {},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]', 
 'ResultClientGrp': '[{"client_group_id":1,"client_group_no":"16000001}]"}
```

But in browser console:

```
{"Page":"1",
 "TotalPage":"538",
 "CurrentPage":"53794",
 "Total":"53794",
 "Data":" [{\"id\":52523,\"_no\":323,\"masteno\":18,\"deletes\":0,\"NAME\":\"XXXXX YYYYY\",}......etc
```

```
search_response = session.post(url, data=data,params=parameters)
                    print(search_response.json())
                    data = (search_response.json()['Data'])
                    for order in json.loads(data):
                           print(order)
```

Expected as:

```
52523
538
53794.....etc
```

Comment: Please refer to [StackCverflow's guideline](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to properly post a question. You are using tags for scrapy when you are NOT using scrapy, nor do I see BS4 code so they should be removed from tags. You should post the URL you are trying to parse as well as the full "request" code in question.

Comment: Removed. Do you have any idea about the above Question?

Comment: Please provide to URL in question to help troubleshoot, but just a thought, when your set  ```data = (search_response.json()['Data'])```, I don't get why then you use the use ```json.loads()``` again, should already be a JSON variable.

Comment: We just can't test without any additional information. Can you provide URL of the resource you are getting the data from?